# show all rows and cols from print jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to print a 50 x 32 numerical data from a text file, this is what i have done:

```
p=np.loadtxt('dataset\Pos0.txt')

print(np.shape(p),'\n')
```

however, my rows and cols are truncated.

I have also tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataset\Pos0.txt')

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 50)

print(df)
```

although the rows and cols are not truncated, due to the space in between values, the return also includes \t.

is there any way i can achieve no truncation while not including the \t?

Comment: Probably, your separator is `\t`. Use `pd.read_csv('dataset\Pos0.txt', sep="\t")` to load the file.

Comment: hey, thanks alot, it solved the issue. appreciate the help

Comment: Nice. Added as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, your separator is `\t`. Use `pd.read_csv('dataset\Pos0.txt', sep="\t")` to load the file.